# How do I control an "if" statement with booleans?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a god simulator in python, sort of like Prayr, but I'm having trouble with the saving part, which I like to get done first. Every time I try to control my `if` statement with booleans, an error saying `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` appears. How can I fix this?

Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from os import path
import random
from tkinter import simpledialog

filename = 0
followers = 0
loadedgame = False

def on_closing():
   if loadedgame == False():
        os.remove(filename)
        f = open(filename, "w+")
        f.write(str(followers))
        root2.destroy()
   else:
       f = open(filename, "w+")
       f.write(str(followers))
       root2.destroy()

def play():
    root2 = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root2.geometry("600x400")
    root2.title("God Sim")
    Label(root2, text="Followers:").pack()
    loadedgame = False

    root2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root = Tk()
root.title("God Sim")
root.geometry("600x400")

Label(root, text="God Sim").pack()
Button(root, text="New", command=play).pack()

# simpledialog.askstring("Input", "")

# filenumber = random.randint(1, 9999999999)
#   filename = str(filenumber) + ".txt"
```

The comments are things I'm going to add to the code once this problem is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Change from False() to False...

Comment: You might want to swap `if` and `else` and just use `if loadedgame:`.

Comment: You want `if not loadedgame` or `if loadedgame is False`

Comment: `if loadedgame is False:` or perhaps better `if not loadedgame:`

Comment: You don't use `is` on `False`.

Comment: You'll also need `global loadedgame` in `play()` to write to the global flag!

Comment: @KlausD. Why is this? If `loadedgame` is meant to be a bool then `is False` would ensure that it is a `bool` and `False` (not `None` or something else)?

Comment: `is` checks for object identify, `==` checks for value equality. In the given case `is` works only because of CPython internal optimizations. It might not work in other Python interpreters or even versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bool object `False` is not a function, and hence is not callable. It is done as `if loadedgame == False:`. Also, do `loadedgame is False` only when your `loadedgame` type is bool. `is` doesn't work if int or any other type is compared to bool.

Answer (score 0):

You should check conditions with booleans using `is`. Also, it is probably an honest mistake but you have put method calling brackets after False, since it's not a method but a value it is not callable.
Here's how you should modify your code

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from os import path
import random
from tkinter import simpledialog

filename = 0
followers = 0
loadedgame = False

def on_closing():
   if not loadedgame:
        os.remove(filename)
        f = open(filename, "w+")
        f.write(str(followers))
        root2.destroy()
   else:
       f = open(filename, "w+")
       f.write(str(followers))
       root2.destroy()

def play():
    root2 = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root2.geometry("600x400")
    root2.title("God Sim")
    Label(root2, text="Followers:").pack()
    loadedgame = False

    root2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root = Tk()
root.title("God Sim")
root.geometry("600x400")

Label(root, text="God Sim").pack()
Button(root, text="New", command=play).pack()

# simpledialog.askstring("Input", "")

# filenumber = random.randint(1, 9999999999)
#   filename = str(filenumber) + ".txt"
```

Comment: Actually, the correct syntax is `if not loadedgame`. And `global loadedgame` should be added to the `play()` function.